# Netgear Dgn2200v4 Cli

Tags: networking, command-line, router

I need to edit the pppoa username and password though the Cli as the router is remote to me and my backdoor is slow where the gui timeout but i can get a usable telnet connection up(local network only got ssh to another machine on the network). Dose anyone good source of info about my problem.

Normally I would port forward though ssh to the gui

I am i admit a bit ignorant with router OS

I thought it would be a case of using nvram set, then nvram commit and reboot

Comment: I have found this that has shown me alot of things in common with my router. http://www.zhone.com/support/manuals/docs/62/6211-A2-GB23-00.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Telnet onto the netgear DGN2200 to see full list of parameters

```
    param show
```

This may be filtered by adding a filter

```
    param show foo

    param set name=newVal
    param save
    reboot
```